# Am I using the callback function correctly?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've just learned to use callback functions, and this is the way I'm using them:

```
//click event function 
function elementClick(element, callback) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        callback();
    });
}
```

This allows me to simply trigger a function when an element is clicked like so:

```
elementClick(modalSkipBtn, loadNewCombination);
```

Is this the correct way to be using the callback function? My code is working fine - I am just wondering if this is a appropriate use for this function.

Comment: `element.addEventListener("click", callback)` would be a bit more elegant.

Comment: Also, if your `elementClick` function only does that, it's probably superfluous. You can call `addEventListener` directly: `modalSkipBtn.addEventListener('click', loadNewCombination);`.

Comment: Make sure you manage the `this` variable correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the implementation is correct.
You could also simple write `element.addEventListener("click",callback);`

Or if your function is loadNewCombination()

`element.addEventListener("click",loadNewCombination);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `element.addEventListener("click", callback)`. The reason is that you can pass the function without invoking it (i.e adding `()` after its name). 
`addEventListener` accepts a second argument which is a function in the same exact way your `elementClick` accepts it. and call it within.